# Does :reload work globally in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Say I have two source files in a clojure program and I reload a changed external module using :reload in one of the modukes. Does the reload only occur in scope of the module which calls reload or is the reload in effect for all modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a clojure file is reloaded, then it is reloaded. This is not subject to a scope - it just loads and evaluates whatever is in the file.

What exactly happens then is dependent on what's in the file. For instance, reloading a (def) form overwrites the root binding for that var. Another interesting consequence is that deleting a var in a file and then reloading it will not remove the var.

Require and use also have side-effects beside loading, and a :reload does not mean all other require and use statements that refer to the same file are re-evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

i'm guessing that, by using :reload, you update a namespace on your repl (on your current instance of the java runtime). therefor, my answer would be: it is global (because now your instance of the runtime has the new code)